# Insert output of command into a dictionary an use it

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning the use of dictionay and i need you to give me a hand.

I have a command which the output is something like that:

```
Ford-escort
Ford-mondeo
Ford-focus
Ford-fiesta
citroen-saxo
citroen-c4
audi-a5
audi-a6
renault-megane
```

I get this output with this command:

```
for car in cars:
     print car.name
```

Easy and simple. Now i try to store this output in a dictionary like that:

```
for car in cars:
    cardict['carName'] = car.name
```

Well , i have 2 issues. The first one is that i need only store in the dictionary the 'ford' values, and the second one is that i don't know how to print this dictionary o how to use the values of the dictionary to do another task.

EDIT: My desired format of the dict is {Carname: Ford-fiesta, CarName: Ford-focus....} and my desired output is the same of the original printoutput.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ask three separate questions, all of which are vague. Your example code for storing in a dictionary is bad, since it overwrites the same key repeatedly and you end up with just one entry in the dictionary. So what is the desired format for your dictionary? In your second question, what is the desired format for the printout--the same as your original printout? And your last question is far too vague and broad--what kind of task will you do later? Please clarify your questions.

Comment: Yes, i know, im newbie in python.. The first one, My desired format of the dictionary is: {Car: Ford-fiesta, Car: Ford-focus...}, The second question is the same of the original printout because i have to use only the name of the cars to do another task. And forget the third question :D

Comment: That desired dictionary format is not possible in Python. Each dictionary entry must have a distinct key, but in your example every entry has the key `Car` or `Carname` (you are inconsistent on which to use). If you attempt that in Python you end with with only one entry which will have the last value--all other values will be lost. Also, the way you wrote it, `Car` is a variable. Did you mean the string `"Car"`? You need to change your desired dictionary format. Perhaps you need another data structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you want **is not** a dict. A dict has unique keys. Create a list of namedtuples instead

```
from collections import namedtuple
Car = namedtuple('Car', 'carname, ...')

result = []
for car in cars:
  result.append(Car(carname=..., ))
```

Answer (score 0):

As blue_note mentioned, a dictionary has unique keys, and you can use the namedtuple instead.

If you only want the car name without the model, add this line

```
car = car.split('-')[0]
```

Now you can access car names as follows:

```
result[0].carname
```